# ValueError when trying to convert Dataframe Column into float

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to convert all the data under the Column `Yield_pct` of my dataframe `df` below into float types, but am facing issues doing this. I get the Error `ValueError: could not convert string to float: ' na'` and hence I added the line `if row1['Yield_pct'] != 'na':` to my code below, yet I get the same error after adding this line.

```
              Date      Maturity      Yield_pct Currency
0       1986-01-01          0.25             na      CAD
1       1986-01-02          0.25   0.0948511020      CAD
2       1986-01-03          0.25   0.0972953210      CAD
3       1986-01-06          0.25   0.0965403640      CAD
4       1986-01-07          0.25   0.0953292440      CAD


for (i1, row1) in (df.iterrows()):
    if row1['Yield_pct'] != 'na':
        row1['Yield_pct'] = float(row1['Yield_pct'])
        if isinstance(row1['Yield_pct'], float)==1:
            print('SUCCESS')
        else:
            print('FAILURE')
```

Thank You

**Edit**: This is the lower part of the dataframe `df`:

```
920538  2015-01-19  empty string                     CAD
920539  2015-01-20  empty string                     CAD
920540  2015-01-21  empty string                     CAD
920541  2015-01-22  empty string                     CAD
920542  2015-01-23  empty string                     CAD
920543  2015-01-26  empty string                     CAD
```

Code that I am now using:

```
df = update('CAD')[0]
for (i1, row1) in (df.iterrows()):
    df = df.convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)
    if isinstance(row1['Yield_pct'], float)==1:
        print('SUCCESS')
    else:
        print('FAILURE')
```

Comment: What's your question? Notice that your error says you cannot convert string ' na' to a float. You're  missing the space before the 'na' in your code. That's a starting place.

Comment: `convert_objects` can handle empty strings

Comment: @EdChum Thank You. However, when I try this `FAILURE` still keeps getting printed out.

Comment: Please edit you question with the code you tried that now doesn't work

Comment: @EdChum Just edited it.

Comment: I don't know why you repeatedly call `convert_objects`, you just need to call it once, also when you claim it fails, after calling `convert_objects` what does `df.info()` show? You may be getting what you think is an error because the `dtype` is actually `np.float64`

Comment: @EdChum Works fine now. I shouldn't have been calling it repeatedly. Thank you very much.

Comment: This is deprecated since version 0.21 unfortunately in favor of astype or specific conversion functions like pd.to_numeric, pd.to_datetime, pd.to_timedelta

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use [`convert_objects`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.convert_objects.html#pandas.DataFrame.convert_objects), it will coerce any duff values into `NaN`:

```
In [75]:
df = df.convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)
df

Out[75]:
         Date  Maturity  Yield_pct Currency
0  1986-01-01      0.25        NaN      CAD
1  1986-01-02      0.25   0.094851      CAD
2  1986-01-03      0.25   0.097295      CAD
3  1986-01-06      0.25   0.096540      CAD
4  1986-01-07      0.25   0.095329      CAD
```

Comment: I didn't know this was a thing. Beautiful.

Comment: @EdChum Thank You. But when I try the lines `df = df.convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)
    row1['Yield_pct'] = float(row1['Yield_pct'])` I don't know why this is.

Comment: I don't understand your comment, using `convert_objects` you don't need any further casting

Comment: @EdChum Unfortunately all the data in the Column are Strings, so I still need to convert those into `float` and so I use `row1['Yield_pct'] = float(row1['Yield_pct'])`. If I use `df = df.convert_objects(convert_numeric=True) ` alone,  I won't be able to satisfy this requirement.

Comment: Does `df['Yield_pct'] = df['Yield_pct'].astype(np.float64)` work? If it doesn't work it's because you have some strange values that you've not shown in your sample data, can you post this

Comment: @EdChum This doesn't work either. I'll update the questions with a bigger sample set.